# How to retrieve id of object that has min value of a complex nested field

Tags: json, jq

This is my file **myfile.gz**, it's a stream of objects like this:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "type": "A",
    "count": 23,
    "monday": {
      "totalMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 80,
          "CLOTHES": 23,
          "TRAVEL": 0
        }
      },
      "usedMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 70,
          "CLOTHES": 20,
          "TRAVEL": 10
        }
      },
      "remainingMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 40,
          "CLOTHES": 5,
          "TRAVEL": 6
        }
      }
    },
    "tuesday": {
      "totalMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 20,
          "CLOTHES": 43,
          "TRAVEL": 50
        }
      },
      "usedMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 20,
          "CLOTHES": 19,
          "TRAVEL": 10
        }
      },
      "remainingMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 55,
          "CLOTHES": 5,
          "TRAVEL": 69
        }
      }
    },
    "wednesday": {
      "totalMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 990,
          "CLOTHES": 443,
          "TRAVEL": 550
        }
      },
      "usedMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 220,
          "CLOTHES": 193,
          "TRAVEL": 110
        }
      },
      "remainingMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 525,
          "CLOTHES": 51,
          "TRAVEL": 619
        }
      }
    }, ...
}
{
    "id": "54321",
    "type": "B",
    "count": 3,
    "monday": {
      "totalMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 80,
          "CLOTHES": 23,
          "TRAVEL": 0
        }
      },
      "usedMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 70,
          "CLOTHES": 20,
          "TRAVEL": 10
        }
      },
      "remainingMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 40,
          "CLOTHES": 5,
          "TRAVEL": 6
        }
      }
    },
    "tuesday": {
      "totalMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 20,
          "CLOTHES": 43,
          "TRAVEL": 50
        }
      },
      "usedMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 20,
          "CLOTHES": 19,
          "TRAVEL": 10
        }
      },
      "remainingMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 55,
          "CLOTHES": 5,
          "TRAVEL": 69
        }
      }
    },
    "wednesday": {
      "totalMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 990,
          "CLOTHES": 443,
          "TRAVEL": 550
        }
      },
      "usedMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 220,
          "CLOTHES": 193,
          "TRAVEL": 110
        }
      },
      "remainingMoney": {
        "categories": {
          "FOOD": 525,
          "CLOTHES": 51,
          "TRAVEL": 619
        }
      }
    }, ...
} ...
```

I want to select and return the object **ID** which is of **type** *S*, **count** > *20*, and **remainingMoney** for **FOOD** inside **categories** on a **friday** is the *least* among all the other objects. This is my first time using jq so I am super lost and confused on how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please give a better example and provide expected output for that example. It is not clear what "least among all the other objects" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-s` to turn the stream into an array, then `map(select(…))` to filter by your criteria, find the minimum using `min_by(…)` with your other criteria, and finally output your desired field `.id`. Add parameter `-r` (next to `-s`) if you want the output as raw text instead of JSON strings.

```bash
jq -s '
  map(select(.type == "S" and .count > 20))
  | min_by(.friday.remainingMoney.categories.FOOD)
  | .id
'
```